Djangoのデータベースを設定しない方法
ここ一週間ばかりDjangoを使い始めたばかりの者です。
行いたいことは
「CSVファイルをpython+Djangoで読み込んで、その値をmodels.py内のClassに保存したい」です。
このImporting CSV Data into Django Modelsを参照に行っております。
現状は、このコードを参照すると[#3]までは終わりました。
現在[#4 Run the Script]でDatabaseエラーが発生しております。
問題が発生してどうしても自力では解決できず、皆様のお知恵を拝借したいです。
具体的には
python manage.py migrate

を行った時のエラーは
「django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.」
これはDATABASESが設定されていないために起きる問題だと理解しております。
しかし、自作のコードではDATABASESを以下のように設定して使わないようにしております。
settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    }
}

他のサイトを参考に解決を試ンでいますが、どうしてもわからず、ここにいたります。
もし解決方法がわかりましたら、ご教授頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。
こちらの開発環境は
Django 5.1.4
Python 3.10.12
Google colabを使用しております。

この記事 What is the difference between django.db.backends.dummy and django.db.backends.mysql? だとそのENGINE設定(空文字列に設定したのと同じ)では常にエラーが発生すると書かれていますね。その設定ではエラーは免れないのでは？ そして参考にしている他サイトとはこの記事 【Django】DBを使用せずに、csvで認証・アカウント管理を行う ではないかと思われますが、この記事はログイン用のユーザー名・パスワードをDBではなくCSVで管理する方法を示しているだけ(しかもmodels.pyの中で特殊な処理をしているようですし)であって、Djangoで行う実際のサービスがDB無しで出来ると言う内容では無いのでは？ 実現しようとして参照している記事も、2. Prepare the CSV FileではCSVとDjangoモデルのフィールド内容と列順番が一致していること、と書かれています。

ありがとうございます。紹介して頂いたサイトを参考に試しいてみましたが、やはり同じ問題（django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.）に行き当たりました。もしかしたらgoogle colab上で開発しているのが律速になっているかもしれません。引き続き調べてみますが、何かありましたら、助言を頂けると幸いです。

どうも誤解していたようです。XY問題 なのでは？ CSVファイルからmodels.pyを作りたい場合にDjangoのプロジェクトをデータベース設定無しで作るのではなく、CSVファイルからmodels.pyを作るツールを使えば良いのでは？ Django CSV Importer, Django Import/Export など。他にこんな記事も。 What's the easiest way to Import a CSV file into a Django Model?, Django, Python: Best way to parse a CSV and convert to Django model instances

Google colabを使ってdjangoを動かすことはできません。実現したいことを明確にした上で、詰まっているところの問題がどこにあるのか質問した方がいいかもしれません。

こんな記事 Running Django on Google Colab., Running Django on Google Colab (タイトルは同じですがこちらはQ&A記事), Is there a general way to run Web Applications on Google Colab, Is there a general way to run Web Applications on Google Colab? もあるのでGoogle Colabでも出来なくはないでしょうが、色々と注意は必要そうですね。ローカルPCで構築するかレンタルサーバー等のサービスを使った方が環境固有の問題に足を引っ張られることは少なくなるのでは？
